# $1999$ Iberoamerican Number theory problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Let $n$ be an integer greater than 10 such that everyone of its digits belongs to the set $S$=$\{1,3,7,9\}$. Show that $n$ has a prime divisor greater than or equal to 11.

Obviously n cannot have prime divisor 2 or 5 , now I have to show that n cannot equal to number of form $3^j 7^k$...

Till now I figured out that product of any two numbers of S taken mod 20 is still in the set itself..but I am not able to make any progress beyond this.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, why do you have to show that $n$ cannot equal to a number of the form $3^j7^k$ ?

Comment: @IntegrateThis  $n$ cannot have prime factors $2 $ or $5$ because of the unit digit and if it does not have any prime factor greater than or equal to $11$, what can be the prime factors of $n$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $n=3^j7^k$ for $j,k \geq 0$. Let $A=\{1,3,7,9\}$. By $mA$ we will denote the set
$\{m,3m,7m,9m\}$. Then observe that (this is simple multiplication and then taking mod)
\begin{align*}
\{3,9,21,27\}=3A & \equiv A \pmod{20}\\
7A & \equiv A \pmod{20}.
\end{align*}
Now we can use induction to prove that $3^j7^k \in A \pmod{20}$.This means $n$ has an even digit in the tens place (a contradiction).

Comment: How $3A \equiv A \pmod{20}\\$ ??? How two sets can be congruent .

Comment: @Ishan That's just a made-up (shorthand) notation to say that when you apply $\mod 20$ to each entry of the set $3A$, then you end up getting the same set as $A$.

Comment: Why does this mean $n$ has an even digit in the tens place?

Comment: @IntegrateThis Think of it this way: if we have $n=100(x)+10y+z$, where $x$ is some integer and $y,z \in \{0,1,2, \ldots, 9\}$are the digits. Then $n \equiv 10y+z \pmod{20}$. If $y$ is even then $n \equiv z \pmod{20}$, otherwise $n \equiv 10+z \pmod{20}$.